# $(window).scroll(fn) vs. $("html,body").scroll(fn)

Tags: jquery, scroll

I know the most cross-browser way to get or set scroll offset is: `$(window).scrollTop()` as a getter, `$('html,body').scrollTop(offset)` as a setter.

But i'm confused about what's the best practise to handle the scroll event?

`$(window).scroll(fn)` or `$("html,body").scroll(fn)`?

Comment: As jQuery itself uses `$( window ).scroll` as example in the documentation (`The scroll event is sent to an element [...]. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements [...]`), I would consider it as the _correct_ way for jQuery. But if you change the `overflow` of `html` or `body`  you might use something else.

Answer (score -1):

i would rather use .bind

```
 $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e){ });
```

Comment: You should explain why you would use `.bind`, and why `mousewheel` instead of `scroll`.

Comment: [**MDN mousewheel**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel): `Note: Gecko doesn't have a plan to implement this event due to legacy event type and non-standard.`